# How to set coefficient limit in lasso regression in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, data-science-model, lasso

I'm working on a regression problem where I want to use Lasso model. With the help of Lasso and LassoCV, we can provide different alpha values and get the best parameter and coefficients however I couldn't find option to set limit or direction for coefficients.

Ex. I have 3 independent variables I1, I2 and I3. I want my I1 and I2 coefficients to be in range(0 , +inf) and I3 in (-inf, 0). Can someone please guide how can I set this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-learn (which I'm assuming you're using) does not allow you to constrain the coefficients in such a way (at most you can constrain them to all be positive with `positive=True`).

However you will find a custom estimator implementation which achieves what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50410037/16779958.

Comment: The first paragraph can solve the specific example in the Question: negate the feature `I3` and then add the `positive=True` parameter.